# Content overflow in storyboard

Tags: ios

When building an interface in xcode 4.2 (using storybaord) what happens if the content is bigger than the screen in storyboard.  I Can scroll text ok using scroll view  but how do i set out images or text boxes buttons etc when i cant edit the physical screen size?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have content in a scene larger than the fixed size in the storyboard, you can scroll within the scene with a two-finger drag. I think that is what you mean, please let me know if not.

From your comment you seem to be stuck at an earlier stage - actually telling the scene you want a larger area in the first place. To do this you have to add a UIScrollView (or UITableView in static mode) to your scene first, then add your text input boxes to that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the two finger drag just moves the items  off the scene and disappears.  I want to lay out lots of text input boxes and dont understand how to make the scene bigger/longer to add the boxes.  At the moment when i reach the bottom of the screen i have to add another screen.

Comment: If this answer has helped, please consider accepting it (there is a checkmark under the answer score). This lets others know your question is answered, and helps you get more answers in the future.